# Read text and input file text to JTextArea

Tags: java, text, jtextarea

What's wrong with my code? I'm trying to read text file and then put the text to `JTextArea`, but its input only consists of the last line of text. What's wrong?

**Code**:

```
public void read() {
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        pavadinimas = file.getName();
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fc.getCurrentDirectory() + "/" + pavadinimas);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                tekstas.setText(strLine);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the append function instead of settext

Comment: Extend: because setText(...) override the text everytime you use it. Append add the new text to the old text in this component.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There is no need to write looping code or append you own end-of-line string.

Use the `JTextArea.read(...)` method.